# When do the seasons and moon phase change in Illyriad?

Tags: illyriad

When do the seasons and moon phase change in Illyriad?  If it's tied to a physical location, where would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Forum Help Files:](http://forum.illyriad.co.uk/6-environment-seasons-lunar-phases_topic119.html)

> The ingame Seasons and the Lunar Phases mirror the Real World clock for the Northern Hemisphere of our lovely planet Earth.  This is by design, to enable people to plan forward by using a simple RL device, such as a calendar.

The seasons work on a simplified monthly calendar, where Winter covers December - February, Spring covers March - May, and so forth.

The lunar cycle is on a 28 day lunar calendar, very similar to the real lunar cycle.